# transaction ran out of gas

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas, error

No matter how much gas i provide this one function it failsas it runs out of gas, i have used a tool to check how much gas it is using and it is not overly high compared to other functions. I cant see the problem in the cde at all. I have even tried re ordering functions but no luck. The function is below someone please help me its one of the last things i need sorted . Thanks in advance.

```
function revokeAffiliate(address _addr) public onlyOwner returns(bool) {
    require(isAffiliate[_addr]);
    isAffiliate[_addr] = false;
    affiliateCodeToAddr[affiliateCodeOfAddr[_addr]] = address(0);
    emit AffiliatePartnershipRevoked(_addr, affiliateCodeOfAddr[_addr]);
    affiliateCodeOfAddr[_addr] = "No longer an affiliate partner";
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I have tried giving it more gas over and over in remix vm, i have tried using a tool to see the gas usage and match that then up it and still failing its making no sense to me

Comment: Looks like we ran into the same problem. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/126292/i-made-a-dead-simple-contract-that-breaks-remix-can-someone-try-it-and-tell-me I think this is a remix bug?

Comment: @destructioneth i managed to sort mine it was due to a code error good luck with yours

Answer (score 0):

I think the gas is high because you are trying

`affiliateCodeToAddr[affiliateCodeOfAddr[_addr]] = address(0)`.
As, affiliateCodeToAddr mapping seems to have string as it's key.

Try to encode the string to bytes through abi.encode. Or, use some sort of indexes for each key. Like 0 could represent "No longer an affiliate partner", 1 could represent something arbitary, and so on.

Comment: Ye i managed to work that out aswell was a simple order error. Thanks for confirming this tho.