# I made a dead simple contract that breaks remix. Can someone try it and tell me if I'm doing anything wrong?

Tags: remix, gas

Setting a variable on a contract to something and then trying to set it back to the default value will result in Remix failing to estimate gas.

[image]

[image]

I was debugging a more complex contract and it took me hours to find out the transaction was reverting because of this.

Comment: Various issues have been raised in the project repo since yesterday - I imagine yours is related and has the same cause -> https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/issues

Comment: (Actually, probably only this one? https://github.com/ethereum/remix-project/issues/2307)

Comment: Yep, they are looking into it! https://twitter.com/EthereumRemix/status/1515401887129907202